# Ignore data validation errors in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am using the data validation functionality to create a drop-down menu.  The menu options are populated via the "List from a range" criteria option in the data validation dialog box.

The menu list is really long, so it only lists "available tasks".  When a task is completed, it disappears from the range that the data validation points to, and therefore is removed from the menu.

This then creates the `"Invalid: Input must fall within specified range"` error, which is true, but because I am using this feature as a dynamic menu rather than actual data validation, I want to ignore it and not see the little red triangles all over my sheet.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

there are ways how to get rid of it but all of them are nasty...

- for a red triangle, you can paint cell background to red **#FF5621** so it would match the triangle color

  [image: 0]
- also you can overlay the red triangle with a drawing filled with white color

  [image: 0] [image: 0]
- for the error message you can use AdblockPlus feature **Block element** to hide the whole popup error window entering this into the blacklist:

  ```
  docs.google.com##.annotation-attribution.annotation-attribution-rebranded.annotation-attribution-invalid
  ```

  [image: 0]

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Yeah, those are pretty nasty especially since the sheet has a lot of users, and would require AdblockPlus on everyone's machine.